# Es posible hacer un DataSet en c# sin saber el número de columnas?

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset

me gustaría hacer un DataSet utilizando un procedimiento almacenado con columnas dinámicas para utilizarlo al generar reportes. El problema es que por lo que he visto sólo hacen DataSets sabiendo la cantidad de columnas de ante mano para asignarle el nombre y tipo de dato. **Es posible hacer un DataSet sin saber el número de columnas?, dinámico por así decirlo**
Muchas gracias por su atención y que tengan un buen día

Comment: Una de las formas es que el resultado de una consulta la almacenes en una Lista o ArrayList y crees un constructor el cual estableces los datos que has de recibir y los guardas en el ArrayList y mediante un foreach y métodos puedes llenar tu DataSet.

Comment: Publica el código en el que realizas la consulta y dónde tienes el problema. No son los objetos `DataSet` los que tienen columnas si no los `DataTable`. Las librerías de acceso a datos de .NET suelen tener métodos que ya te devuelven un `DataTable` a partir del resultado de la consulta (o ejecución de procedimiento almacenado). Habría que ver cómo lo estás intentando hacer para ver el problema.